# Logrotate not rotating logs on AWS Linux

Tags: linux, logrotate

I have a problem with Logrotate not rotating logs on one of my Amazon Linux machines. This box uses rsyslog and receives logs from other devices. As such a wildcard rule was used and I thought that was the problem, though removing it doesn't help. I've tried forcing a rotation using logrotate -fv, but while it says the logs should be rotated, a dateext archive of the log is not created in /var/log. The odd thing is this was working up until July and due to some change made at that time, it stopped working. Here's the logrotate config for the rsyslog files (/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog):

```
/var/log/cron
/var/log/maillog
/var/log/messages
/var/log/secure
/var/log/spooler
/var/log/boot.log
/var/log/system-*.log{
    compress
    notifempty
    daily
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
         service rsyslog restart >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
    endscript
}
```

Here is the output from a logrotate -fv commmand:

```
reading config file /etc/logrotate.conf
including /etc/logrotate.d
reading config file dracut
reading config info for /var/log/dracut.log
reading config file psacct
reading config info for /var/account/pacct
reading config file rsyslog
reading config info for /var/log/cron
/var/log/maillog
/var/log/messages
/var/log/secure
/var/log/spooler
/var/log/boot.log
/var/log/system-*.log
reading config file yum
reading config info for /var/log/yum.log
reading config info for /var/log/wtmp
reading config info for /var/log/btmp

Handling 6 logs

rotating pattern: /var/log/dracut.log  forced from command line (4 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/dracut.log
  log does not need rotating

rotating pattern: /var/account/pacct  forced from command line (31 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/account/pacct
  log does not need rotating
not running postrotate script, since no logs were rotated

rotating pattern: /var/log/cron
/var/log/maillog
/var/log/messages
/var/log/secure
/var/log/spooler
/var/log/boot.log
/var/log/system-*.log forced from command line (4 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/cron
  log needs rotating
considering log /var/log/maillog
  log needs rotating
considering log /var/log/messages
error: stat of /var/log/messages failed: No such file or directory
considering log /var/log/secure
  log needs rotating
considering log /var/log/spooler
error: stat of /var/log/spooler failed: No such file or directory
considering log /var/log/boot.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /var/log/system-10.0.1.5.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /var/log/system-10.10.200.1.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /var/log/system-10.50.10.1.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /var/log/system-10.70.10.1.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /var/log/system-usawsnet01.log
  log needs rotating
rotating log /var/log/cron, log->rotateCount is 4
dateext suffix '-20160916'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
rotating log /var/log/maillog, log->rotateCount is 4
dateext suffix '-20160916'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
rotating log /var/log/secure, log->rotateCount is 4
dateext suffix '-20160916'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
rotating log /var/log/boot.log, log->rotateCount is 4
dateext suffix '-20160916'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
glob finding old rotated logs failed
rotating log /var/log/system-10.0.1.5.log, log->rotateCount is 4
dateext suffix '-20160916'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
glob finding old rotated logs failed
rotating log /var/log/system-10.10.200.1.log, log->rotateCount is 4
dateext suffix '-20160916'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
glob finding old rotated logs failed
rotating log /var/log/system-10.50.10.1.log, log->rotateCount is 4
dateext suffix '-20160916'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
glob finding old rotated logs failed
rotating log /var/log/system-10.70.10.1.log, log->rotateCount is 4
dateext suffix '-20160916'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
glob finding old rotated logs failed
rotating log /var/log/system-usawsnet01.log, log->rotateCount is 4
dateext suffix '-20160916'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
glob finding old rotated logs failed

rotating pattern: /var/log/yum.log  forced from command line (4 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/yum.log
  log does not need rotating

rotating pattern: /var/log/wtmp  forced from command line (1 rotations)
empty log files are rotated, only log files >= 1048576 bytes are rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/wtmp
  log needs rotating
rotating log /var/log/wtmp, log->rotateCount is 1
dateext suffix '-20160916'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
destination /var/log/wtmp-20160916 already exists, skipping rotation

rotating pattern: /var/log/btmp  forced from command line (1 rotations)
empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/btmp
  log /var/log/btmp does not exist -- skipping
```

It does claim the logs need rotation and force should do that, but after running this I only have the following files in /var/log (note the properly rotated logs prior to Jul 24):

```
-rw-------  1 root root  385 Jul 21 03:13 secure-20160720.gz
-rw-------  1 root root  303 Jul 22 03:35 secure-20160721.gz
-rw-------  1 root root  908 Jul 22 03:35 cron-20160721.gz
-rw-------  1 root root  896 Jul 23 03:31 cron-20160722.gz
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Jul 23 19:45 mail
-rw-------  1 root root  329 Jul 24 03:17 secure-20160722.gz
-rw-------  1 root root  884 Jul 24 03:17 cron-20160723.gz
-rw-------  1 root root 2.5K Aug 17 21:25 yum.log-20160916
-rw-------  1 root root  218 Aug 30 03:25 maillog-20160707.gz
-rw-------  1 root root 4.0K Sep 15 04:33 maillog
-rw-rw-r--  1 root utmp  66K Sep 15 23:20 wtmp-20160916
-rw-------  1 root root    0 Sep 16 00:16 dracut.log
-rw-------  1 root root    0 Sep 16 00:16 yum.log
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  36K Sep 16 03:21 .
-rw-------  1 root root 307K Sep 16 04:01 cron
-rw-------  1 root root  32K Sep 16 04:09 secure
-rw-------  1 root root 3.9G Sep 16 04:09 boot.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 root utmp 4.2K Sep 16 17:48 wtmp
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 144K Sep 16 17:48 lastlog
-rw-------  1 root root  11K Sep 16 18:01 system-usawsnet01.log
-rw-------  1 root root 141M Sep 16 18:14 system-10.50.10.1.log
-rw-------  1 root root 5.2G Sep 16 18:14 system-10.0.1.5.log
-rw-------  1 root root 5.8G Sep 16 18:14 system-10.70.10.1.log
-rw-------  1 root root 5.2G Sep 16 18:14 system-10.10.200.1.log
```

Finally, here's the base logrotate config file in case it helps:

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# use date as a suffix of the rotated file
dateext

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# RPM packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# no packages own wtmp and btmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
    minsize 1M
    rotate 1
}

/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0600 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

# system-specific logs may be also be configured here.
```

I've tried removing the wildcard  and I've removed /var/lib/logrotate.status to start over, but nothing seems to trigger the rotation of these logs.

Comment: What changes were made that caused this ?

Comment: Why don't you execute the command with only one log file line activated and set the others as comment? I guess one of the errors or warnings prevents logrotate from doing what it pretends to do.

Comment: Are you running the `logrotate -fv` command as root? Is SELinux enabled on the machine?

Comment: No, we're not sure what we changed to cause this. Selinux is not enabled and the lograte -fv command was done using sudo. Good idea to pare down to isolate the problem. We have tried that, in particular removing the system-*.log wildcard thinking that was the problem, but the other logs in that config item did not start archiving daily after doing so. I'm going to try this again,  setting up two separate config statements for the standard rsyslog handled system logs and another for just one of the remote logs, using an explicit name.

Comment: Learned it works if I create config entries for each log individually. Any config entry that specifies multiple logs, including the wildcard spec, does not rotate any of them. I don't think it's a problem for rsyslog in closing and reopening logs, but I do lose the flexibility of automatically handling new logs we add by way of the wildcard. Also odd that it's not working even for the base system logs.

Comment: Can rsyslog be the culprit here? I wouldn't think it would have any effect in how logrotate parses and executes the config entries, but I do have logrotate working fine for multiple logs config entries on other AWS Linux boxes using syslogd.